# Arduino an sparkfun microled problem

Tags: arduino-uno

In on of my projects i am using sparkfuns MicrOLED library. Downloaded it from github, installed as usual but no code calling that library compiles. Error is SPF_MicrOLED.h no such file or directory.

It is strange as the library is installed, example sketches are in the examples menu but they don`t want to compile ether, same error. Not sure what to do. Tried also to rename microled library folder but same error.

Comment: First, like most all of us, I started with the Blink program.  It is the first way I could see how the IDE worked.  Compile, upload, observe.  It would be very helpful if you could let us know how that acts.

Comment: The question is fine and perfectly clear as it encapsulates the obvious problem of mistyping the name of the library which has been identified below.  That might not be the *only* problem, but it is a problem that makes a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2):

> Error is SPF_MicrOLED.h no such file or directory.

That is to be expected because the [library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Micro_OLED_Arduino_Library) doesn't contain a file named SPF_MicrOLED.h.

It does contain a file named [SFE_MicroOLED.h](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Micro_OLED_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/SFE_MicroOLED.h). Use the correct filename in your `#include` and the problem will be solved.